# ARM assembly - Are registers guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, arm, size

I'm working on a small program to learn a bit of ARM assembly and how it interacts with C. What I'm trying to do right now is calling an assembly function from C and passing it a pointer as an parameter.

Now, I know a single parameter will usually be stored in r0, but I was wondering if this applies to pointers as well. Is there any case where the CPU's registers won't be large enough to hold a pointer? What if I tried to pass it, say, a struct by value?

While I'm testing this on a Cortex-A8 based board, I'd like to know if (at least theoretically) this could happen in some other architecture. If that was the case, is there a platform-agnostic way of knowing how large it is (other than using sizeof in C)?

Comment: This falls squarely into the domain of the ABI. I don't know offhand which ABI applies to C on ARM, but there is certainly one, and hopefully *only* one.

Comment: [Here's the official ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The CPU registers on a Cortex A8 are 32 bits wide so a pointer will fit in there just fine.  That's kind of the idea.  You have a bigger problem though - there's no guarantee that any parameter will be passed in any register even if it fits.  A c compiler is free to pass parameters any way it wants, even by carrier pigeon.

You *may* be able to answer the question "How does {the compiler you're using} pass a pointer?", but you probably need to know the full signature of the function, whether or not any compiler-specific flags are in effect, maybe the return value? etc. . .

*"What if I tried to pass it, say, a struct by value?"* is even harder.  The answer is "Probably gets passed on the stack" (the stack being another implementation detail!) but there's other insidious details too like - At the end of the function, who decrements the stack pointer?  The caller or the callee?  Is there any special alignment requirement (probably yes!) etc.

If you *really* want to write assembly, you might be better off using compiler-specific extensions that let you write assembly - but *inside* a c function.  That way some of the really difficult stuff gets handled for you.

Comment: Indeed, I'll see what documentation can I get. I'm using the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf toolchain, so I guess there must be some docs specifying how it'll handle the parameter passing.

Comment: "the memory bus", and its relation to pointers, is a bit vague, really - consider Cortex-A15, where pointers are 32 bits, physical addresses are 64 bits, the address bus is 40 bits and the data bus is 128 bits ;)

Comment: Also, "there's no guarantee that any parameter will be passed in any register even if it fits" is totally incorrect in this case. The compiler _must_ guarantee to follow the defined ABI when calling any external function, or _nothing would work_. Sure it can play fast and loose _inside_ it's own objects, but it doesn't even know external code _exists_ until linking.

Comment: In ARM a register may store the address of a process but may not store the whole address range like the case of LPAE

Comment: @Notlikethat: The compiler might do that for functions defined as static. In that case it KNOWS that the function will not be used outside the current file. But in any other case the compiler should (and will) follow the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

what if? ... well just try it:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int a[30];
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int d;
} HELLO;

void more_fun ( unsigned int, unsigned int, HELLO );

HELLO b;

void fun ( void )
{
    HELLO a;

    a.a[7]=5;
    a.b=6;
    a.c=7;
    a.d=8;
    more_fun(1,2,a);
    a.c=12;
    more_fun(66,77,a);
    b.c=12;
    more_fun(44,55,b);
}
```

then compile and disassemble

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c fun.c -o fun.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D fun.o
```

and see what you get...it may be obvious I kept modifying/adding things to see what was really happening.  I wasnt expecting this but it is actually passing by value.  I was expecting it to make a destroy-able copy, and pass a pointer to that.  The arm abi uses r0-r3 first (there are rules for if it uses all of them) then goes to the stack when those run out.  In the above case the first two words are in r2 and r3 and the other 31 are on the stack, the a struct is also on the stack for the fun function, and I got the struct large enough to force it to memcpy rather than a series of ldm/stms.

But to what may be your real question.  If an arm register is not able to hold a "pointer" then how will the architecture work at all?  If/when the address space exceeds a single general purpose register (for which there are register based addressing instructions to date for that architecture) then some scheme as to be added to the architecture.  paging is quite popular, some new register/address holds the upper address bits or a base address to which the register is now an offset not the whole address.  I have not seen anything like this in arm thus far.

And as already answered, since this is a C pointer question not an architecture question, the answer lies strictly in how that C is implemented for that architecture.  And using a word like guaranteed is guaranteed to fail eventually.  In addition to architectures changing over time or not, you have no reason to assume that any two compilers or any two versions or compilations of the same compiler will produce the same results as the other, so maybe it does one thing today, but it can/will do something tomorrow.

As far as your passing a pointer question...just try it and see what the
compiler you are using outputs.  Then if you just want to know or think the compiler is buggy then examine the published calling convention, if there is one (which in this case there is), and see how the code the compiler generated compares to the calling convention.  If your test C code is real or real-ish then that is how that compiler passes that pointer and your asm not only can but must retrieve that pointer from where it was passed for the c/asm interface to work.

And of course if you do anything too complicated in your asm/c interface, it increases your odds that the next time the abi changes your c/asm interface will fail.  Some level of chance of failure is always there with an asm/c interface.  for any compiler on any platform (unless you are the compiler/assembler author and insure you will never change it).

What you can almost always do though is "just try it" and see how the compiler generates the call, where the data is, if the compiler is not buggy then it is following the convention and you can rely on that (for that compiler), if it is buggy then your program may fail anyway with or without asm due to the buggy compiler.